# Azure AD Graph API - Stopped returning values for Group Members, any ideas?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

As the title says, the graph API was working properley and we were reading names and emails of people in the same AD group.

as of a month or so ago, the Group member ID is being returned and nothing else.

initially GroupMember.Read.All was assigned, we have since tried GroupMember.ReadWrite.All still nothing. see below response payload.

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/groupID/members

````
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#directoryObjects",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
            "id": "fc437c6f-8b97-4ea6-9a7a-111111111", // fake number
            "businessPhones": [],
            "displayName": null,
            "givenName": null,
            "jobTitle": null,
            "mail": null,
            "mobilePhone": null,
            "officeLocation": null,
            "preferredLanguage": null,
            "surname": null,
            "userPrincipalName": null
        },```


thanks
````

Answer (score 0):

we had User.Read aswell, but turns out something has changed and we needed to add User.ReadBasic.All

Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue, asked the Admin to add User.ReadBasic.All, waiting. If it works, you get a Upvote :D

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the reason for this, but the permissions required to access list of group members are:

[image]

For more information:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions

Comment: in case u r still facing the issue, try .Groups[groupId].Members.GraphUser.GetAsync();